# fetching database results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ('Connection Error');
mysql_select_db ("streamurl", $connection);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `url`";
$raw = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($raw)){
    echo "<audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src=" . $show['URL'] . " </audio>";
}
?>
```

First of all I'm really new to php and mysql.

In my database i have 2 streaming audio links and i have echoed out those results in an audio tag as you can see in the above code. But results are only showing in 1 audio tag. But I would like to display all the available links to be echoed out in separate audio tags. So a little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not fix, any way you have missed to close the `<audio` tag - `<audio>`

Comment: Interesting, I've never hear of anyone using [PHP with MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) before. No wonder you can't find anything [on the internet](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) that covers [that topic](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php).

Comment: `echo "<audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src=" . $show['URL'] . " ></audio>";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462509/getting-mysql-results-as-php-array

Comment: Is the missing `>` at the end of the `<audio` in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: @naomik that's a  very bad tone. plus his php/mysql code seems correct. the html output is bad because of the missing > to close the tag, as pointed out by the first comment

Comment: @buddhi What does this have to do with making an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with the below code and you are done you just missed a closing audio tag

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ('Connection Error');
    mysql_select_db ("streamurl", $connection);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `url`";
    $raw = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($raw)){
       echo "<audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src=" . $show['URL'] . " ></audio>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the  tag. Try it:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","") or die ('Connection Error');
mysql_select_db ("streamurl", $connection);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `url`";
$raw = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($raw)){
    echo "<audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src=\"{$show['URL']}\"></audio>";
}
?>
```

I've put the src attribute quotes as weel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ('Connection Error');
mysql_select_db("streamurl", $connection);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM url";
$raw = mysql_query($sql);
while ($show = mysql_fetch_array($raw))
{?>
    <audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src="<?php echo $show['URL']; ?>"></audio>
<?php
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is starting point of our coding race.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Database") or die(mysql_error());
$query=mysql_query("select `URL` form `url`") or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<audio controls=yes autoplay=yes src="'.$show['URL'].'"></audio>';
}
?>
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to start using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of MySQL extension, just because that extension is deprecated. So something similar in MySQLi would be:
-http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "streamurl");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo("Connection Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/***************start query****************/
if ($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `url`;", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    while ($show = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<audio controls='yes' autoplay='yes' src='" . $show['URL'] . "'></audio>";
    }

    $result->close();

}
/***************end query****************/
$connection->close();
?>
```

In order to use some parameters in the where clause you just need to change the query section for: 
-http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
/***************start query****************/
$param = "movie"; //any parameter for where clause
if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `url` WHERE param = ?;")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($show = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<audio controls='yes' autoplay='yes' src='" . $show['URL'] . "'></audio>";
    }

    $stmt->close();

}
/***************end query****************/
```